# Twython' object has no attribute 'getUserTimeline'

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm trying to create a bot that will retweet and promote some of my other accounts.  But i receive the below error

```
AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'getUserTimeline'
```

my code is:

```
search_results = twitter.getUserTimeline(sreen_name="SCREENNAME", count = 2,)
try:
for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
    twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"])
except TwythonError as e:
    print e
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the twython documentation about getting a users timeline? What does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [twithon documentation](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#core-interface) there is no getUserTimeline function there is however a get_user_timeline function.

You should change the following call:

```
twitter.getUserTimeline
```

to be:

```
twitter.get_user_timeline
```

Comment: Thank you! that sorted that problem!